# How to disable desktop icons in windows 10 with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, icons, desktop

How to remove icons such as "recycle bin" or "control panel" from the desktop using a powershell command? I'm talking about this setting:

That's the setting I'm looking for

[image]

I found the setting in windows but couldn't find a PowerShell command to do this.

Comment: Hi! Why do you want to do this in powershell? Whats the purpose?

Comment: Is this a school project or are you just trying to do things the hard way?

Comment: Did you mean like this batch file ? : [Show-Hide_Desktop_Icons.bat](https://pastebin.com/kvc4ZCKK)

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle I added it as an answer (-_°)

Answer (score 1):

This batch file is used to change various settings on a Windows computer, such as showing or hiding the seconds in the system clock and showing or hiding desktop icons.

[image]

First, this batch calls a subroutine called **"CreateShortcut"** which creates a shortcut to the batch file on the user's desktop and assigns a hotkey of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to it.

The batch file then uses the **"Net session"** command to check if it is running with administrative rights.

If not, it uses PowerShell to start the shortcut with administrative rights and exits the batch file.

The next section of the code sets a variable **"Key"** to a specific registry key location, which is used later in the code to make changes to the system settings.

The subroutine **"GetInfo"** uses PowerShell to get a list of all the currently opened folders in Windows Explorer and stores them in an array called **"Folder"**.

This is used later in the code to restore the folders after making changes to the system settings.

The batch file then enters a loop labeled **"menuLOOP"**, which displays a menu of options to the user, such as **"Show Seconds In System Clock"** and **"Hide Desktop Icons"**.

The user can make a selection or hit enter to quit the batch file.

The selected option is then passed as a parameter to a subroutine with the corresponding name, such as **"menu_1"**, **"menu_2"**, etc.

Each of these subroutines makes changes to the system settings using the **"reg"** command, which modifies the registry.

For example, **"menu_1"** uses the **"reg add"** command to set the value of the **"ShowSecondsInSystemClock"** key in the registry to 1, which shows the seconds in the system clock.

[image]

After making the changes, the subroutine **"Restart_Explorer"** is called which uses PowerShell to restart Windows Explorer.

Then the batch file uses a for loop to restore all the folders that were opened before making the changes.

---

```bat
@echo off
Title Show Or Hide Desktop Icons And Show Or Hide Seconds In System Clock
Color 9E & Mode 82,12 & SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Call:CreateShortcut
:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Automatically check & and start the batch file with admin rights
(Net session >nul 2>&1)||(PowerShell start """%userprofile%\Desktop\%~n0.lnk""" -verb RunAs & Exit /B)
::--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set "Key=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced"
::--------------------------------------------------------------------------
:GetInfo
@REM Get Opened Folders with PowerShell code in a batch file
Set PSCommand="@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).Document.Folder | ForEach { $_.Self.Path }"
REM  Populate the array with existent and opened folders
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set /a Count=0
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Powershell -C %PSCommand%') do (
    Set /a Count+=1
    Set "Folder[!Count!]=%%a"
)
::===========================================================================
:menuLOOP
::===========================================================================
echo(
echo(
echo(       ***************************** Menu ******************************
echo(
@for /f "tokens=2* delims=_ " %%A in ('"findstr /b /c:":menu_" "%~f0""') do (
echo(                 %%A  %%B)
echo(
echo(       *****************************************************************
echo( &Set /p Selection=Make a Selection or hit ENTER to quit: || Goto :EOF
echo( & Call:menu_[%Selection%]
GOTO:menuLOOP
::===========================================================================
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[1] Show Seconds In SystemClock
reg Add "%Key%" /V ShowSecondsInSystemClock /T REG_DWORD /D 1 /F 1>NUL
Call:Restart_Explorer
@rem Restore all closed folders
@for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do Start /MAX Explorer "!Folder[%%i]!"
Exit /B
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[2] Hide Seconds In SystemClock
reg Add "%Key%" /V ShowSecondsInSystemClock /T REG_DWORD /D 0 /F 1>NUL
Call:Restart_Explorer
@rem Restore all closed folders
@for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do Start /MAX Explorer "!Folder[%%i]!"
Exit /B
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[3] Hide Desktop Icons
reg add "HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" /v NoDesktop /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f 2>nul
Call:Restart_Explorer
@rem Restore all closed folders
@for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do Start /MAX Explorer "!Folder[%%i]!"
Exit /B
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:menu_[4] Show Desktop Icons
reg delete HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer /v NoDesktop /f 2>nul
Call:Restart_Explorer
@rem Restore all closed folders
@for /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do Start /MAX Explorer "!Folder[%%i]!"
Exit /B
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:Restart_Explorer
Powershell -C "gps explorer | spps"
Exit /B
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
:CreateShortcut
Powershell ^
"$s=(New-Object -COM WScript.Shell).CreateShortcut('%userprofile%\Desktop\%~n0.lnk'); ^
$s.TargetPath='%~f0'; ^
$s.WorkingDirectory='%~dp0'; ^
$s.IconLocation='colorcpl.exe,0'; ^
$s.HotKey='CTRL+ALT+I'; ^
$s.Save()"
Exit /B
::---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```